# How to Filter out Django Models

Tags: python, django

How do I create a lesson in a course without it showing in another course. I have a foreign key which is the course and it is under the models Lesson. I want to only view the lesson that is created under the certain course. But my problem is when I create a lesson in course 1, the lesson also shows in course 2. (sorry for bad english)

views.py

```
def lessonpage(request):
    lesson = Lesson.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "lessons/lessons.html", {'lessons': lesson})
    else:
        return redirect('loginpage')

def addlesson(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddLessonForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request, "lessons/successlessons.html", {'form1': form})
    form = AddLessonForm()
    return render(request, "lessons/addlessons.html", {'form': form})

def deletelessons(request, id):
    lesson = Lesson.objects.get(id=id)
    lesson.delete()
    return redirect("lessonspage")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Section(models.Model):
    nameofsection = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nameofsection

class Course(models.Model):
    ctitle = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    cdescription = models.TextField(max_length=200, default="")
    #csection = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ctitle

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ctitle

    class Meta:
        db_table="courses"

class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, default="")
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
path('course/', coursepage, name="coursepage"),
    path('course/<int:pk>', CourseDetailView.as_view(), name='detailed'),
    path('addcourse/', addcourse, name="addcoursepage"),
    path('editcourse/<int:id>', updatecourse, name="editcoursepage"),
    path('updatecourse/<int:id>', updatecourserecord, name="updatecourse"),
    path('deletecourse/<int:id>', deletecourse, name="deletecourse"),

    path('lessons', lessonpage, name="lessonspage"),
    path('lessons/addlessons', addlesson, name="addlessonspage"),
    path('deletelessons/<int:id>', deletelessons, name="deletelessons"),
```

Comment: Which view do you want to render the courses in? You should be able to filter in your views by doing something like `data = Model_Name.objects.filter()` Have a look there https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @PhilM in the lessonpage function